# PHP: Notice when error_reporting(E_ALL)

Tags: php

When I try to access info that is not presented in xml like so: $someInfo = $element->blabla->cats[0]->src;
PHP shows notice like this: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
How would I settle the matter?

Comment: This is a duplicate, are you having trouble with your login?

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the specific element is set befor accessing data:

```
if(isset($element->blabla->cats[0]->src)){
    $someInfo = $element->blabla->cats[0]->src;
}
```