# PHP: Notice when error_reporting(E_ALL)

Tags: php

When I try to access info that is not presented in xml like so: `$someInfo = $element->blabla->cats[0]->src;`
PHP shows notice like this: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`
How would I settle the matter?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345819/php-notice-when-error-reportinge-all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either `$element`, `blabla`, or `cats[0]` is not an object, and thus can't contain any elements.

Use `isset()`:

```
if (isset($element->blabla->cats[0]->src))
 echo $element->blabla->cats[0]->src;
```

one `isset()` should do, no need to check every part consecutively.

This should do the job even if `cats` exists but is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use isset to verify if object property exists, like this:

`if (isset ($element->blabla) && isset ($element->blabla->cats) && etc..)`

if you just don't want to see the notice, use `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE)`

Answer (score 0):

Or alternative (but wrong way) you can suppress log in your php script by:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```

Which will force php to report only fatal errors.

Anyway, use Pekka solution.